# Is there a way to fetch needed information from JSON file in React Native

Tags: json, typescript, react-native

I am using a COVID-19 API (https://api.covidactnow.org/v2/counties.json?apiKey=) that records various information like number of cases and deaths in each county in USA. In my React Native app, I retrieved the user's location, and more specifically, the user's county, state and country. In this case, I have stored the user's county name in `countyName`. I'd like to fetch the specific cases and deaths from the JSON file depending on what is `countyName` is. I have a snippet of one county in the JSON file below. I was thinking I could go into the index of the array and in the actuals, and then fetch the cases and deaths.

```
[
  {
    "fips": "02013",
    "country": "US",
    "state": "AK",
    "county": "Aleutians East Borough",
    "level": "county",
    "lat": null,
    "locationId": "iso1:us#iso2:us-ak#fips:02013",
    "long": null,
    "population": 3337,
    "metrics": {
      "testPositivityRatio": null,
      "testPositivityRatioDetails": {
        "source": "other"
      },
      "caseDensity": 0,
      "contactTracerCapacityRatio": null,
      "infectionRate": 4.71887277063,
      "infectionRateCI90": 1.1615979428900003,
      "icuHeadroomRatio": null,
      "icuHeadroomDetails": null,
      "icuCapacityRatio": null,
      "vaccinationsInitiatedRatio": null,
      "vaccinationsCompletedRatio": 0.27509739286784535
    },
    "riskLevels": {
      "overall": 0,
      "testPositivityRatio": 4,
      "caseDensity": 0,
      "contactTracerCapacityRatio": 4,
      "infectionRate": 3,
      "icuHeadroomRatio": 4,
      "icuCapacityRatio": 4
    },
    "actuals": {
      "cases": 363,
      "deaths": 2,
      "positiveTests": null,
      "negativeTests": null,
      "contactTracers": null,
      "hospitalBeds": {
        "capacity": null,
        "currentUsageTotal": null,
        "currentUsageCovid": null,
        "typicalUsageRate": null
      },
      "icuBeds": {
        "capacity": null,
        "currentUsageTotal": null,
        "currentUsageCovid": null,
        "typicalUsageRate": null
      },
      "newCases": 0,
      "newDeaths": 0,
      "vaccinesDistributed": null,
      "vaccinationsInitiated": null,
      "vaccinationsCompleted": 918,
      "vaccinesAdministered": null,
      "vaccinesAdministeredDemographics": null,
      "vaccinationsInitiatedDemographics": null
    },
    "annotations": {
      "cases": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "NYTimes",
            "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
            "name": "The New York Times"
          }
        ],
        "anomalies": []
      },
      "deaths": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "NYTimes",
            "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
            "name": "The New York Times"
          }
        ],
        "anomalies": []
      },
      "positiveTests": null,
      "negativeTests": null,
      "contactTracers": null,
      "hospitalBeds": null,
      "icuBeds": null,
      "newCases": null,
      "newDeaths": null,
      "vaccinesDistributed": null,
      "vaccinationsInitiated": null,
      "vaccinationsCompleted": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "other",
            "url": "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#county-view",
            "name": "Centers for Disease Control and Prevention"
          }
        ],
        "anomalies": []
      },
      "vaccinesAdministered": null,
      "testPositivityRatio": null,
      "caseDensity": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "NYTimes",
            "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
            "name": "The New York Times"
          }
        ],
        "anomalies": []
      },
      "contactTracerCapacityRatio": null,
      "infectionRate": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "NYTimes",
            "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
            "name": "The New York Times"
          }
        ],
        "anomalies": []
      },
      "infectionRateCI90": {
        "sources": [
          {
            "type": "NYTimes",
            "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
            "name": "The New York Times"
          }
        ],
        "anomalies": []
      },
      "icuHeadroomRatio": null,
      "icuCapacityRatio": null,
      "vaccinationsInitiatedRatio": null,
      "vaccinationsCompletedRatio": null
    },
    "lastUpdatedDate": "2021-04-26",
    "url": "https://covidactnow.org/us/alaska-ak/county/aleutians_east_borough"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that you got from the API in JSON format is an array of objects.
To get the no of deaths and cases from the array of objects, you need to do the following:

```js
    const response= [
        {
        "fips": "02013",
        "country": "US",
        "state": "AK",
        "county": "Aleutians East Borough",
        "level": "county",
        "lat": null,
        "locationId": "iso1:us#iso2:us-ak#fips:02013",
        "long": null,
        "population": 3337,
        "metrics": {
          "testPositivityRatio": null,
          "testPositivityRatioDetails": {
            "source": "other"
          },
          "caseDensity": 0,
          "contactTracerCapacityRatio": null,
          "infectionRate": 4.71887277063,
          "infectionRateCI90": 1.1615979428900003,
          "icuHeadroomRatio": null,
          "icuHeadroomDetails": null,
          "icuCapacityRatio": null,
          "vaccinationsInitiatedRatio": null,
          "vaccinationsCompletedRatio": 0.27509739286784535
         },
         "riskLevels": {
         "overall": 0,
          "testPositivityRatio": 4,
          "caseDensity": 0,
          "contactTracerCapacityRatio": 4,
          "infectionRate": 3,
          "icuHeadroomRatio": 4,
          "icuCapacityRatio": 4
         },
         "actuals": {
         "cases": 363,
          "deaths": 2,
          "positiveTests": null,
          "negativeTests": null,
          "contactTracers": null,
          "hospitalBeds": {
            "capacity": null,
            "currentUsageTotal": null,
            "currentUsageCovid": null,
            "typicalUsageRate": null
          },
          "icuBeds": {
            "capacity": null,
            "currentUsageTotal": null,
            "currentUsageCovid": null,
            "typicalUsageRate": null
          },
          "newCases": 0,
          "newDeaths": 0,
          "vaccinesDistributed": null,
          "vaccinationsInitiated": null,
          "vaccinationsCompleted": 918,
          "vaccinesAdministered": null,
          "vaccinesAdministeredDemographics": null,
          "vaccinationsInitiatedDemographics": null
        },
        "annotations": {
          "cases": {
            "sources": [
              {
                "type": "NYTimes",
                "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
                "name": "The New York Times"
              }
            ],
            "anomalies": []
          },
          "deaths": {
            "sources": [
              {
                "type": "NYTimes",
                "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
                "name": "The New York Times"
              }
            ],
            "anomalies": []
          },
          "positiveTests": null,
          "negativeTests": null,
          "contactTracers": null,
          "hospitalBeds": null,
          "icuBeds": null,
          "newCases": null,
          "newDeaths": null,
          "vaccinesDistributed": null,
          "vaccinationsInitiated": null,
          "vaccinationsCompleted": {
            "sources": [
              {
                "type": "other",
                "url": "https://covid.cdc.gov/covid-data-tracker/#county-view",
                "name": "Centers for Disease Control and Prevention"
              }
            ],
            "anomalies": []
          },
          "vaccinesAdministered": null,
          "testPositivityRatio": null,
          "caseDensity": {
            "sources": [
              {
                "type": "NYTimes",
                "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
                "name": "The New York Times"
              }
            ],
            "anomalies": []
          },
          "contactTracerCapacityRatio": null,
          "infectionRate": {
            "sources": [
              {
                "type": "NYTimes",
                "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
                "name": "The New York Times"
              }
            ],
            "anomalies": []
          },
          "infectionRateCI90": {
            "sources": [
              {
                "type": "NYTimes",
                "url": "https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data",
                "name": "The New York Times"
              }
            ],
            "anomalies": []
          },
          "icuHeadroomRatio": null,
          "icuCapacityRatio": null,
          "vaccinationsInitiatedRatio": null,
          "vaccinationsCompletedRatio": null
        },
        "lastUpdatedDate": "2021-04-26",
        "url": "https://covidactnow.org/us/alaska-ak/county/aleutians_east_borough"
      }
    ]
    const enteredCountryName = "US";
    //Getting the required country name from the array of objects using filter method
    const countryArray = response.filter(item => item.country === enteredCountryName)
    const noOfDeaths = countryArray[0].actuals.deaths;
    const noOfCases = countryArray[0].actuals.cases;
    console.log({noOfDeaths, noOfCases})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in a specific county, there is [an endpoint for this in the API](https://apidocs.covidactnow.org/#data-for-individual-locations). Just query this, then there is no need to filter the fetched data further:

```
https://api.covidactnow.org/v2/county/{fips}.json?apiKey=YOUR_KEY_HERE
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I didn't notice that before.